# Altair layered charts: How to sum over charts?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, sum, altair

I have multiple charts that are in a dictionary index by a parameter and I would like to plot them together in a layered chart by summing over the index. Here is an example of what I want to do and what I have tried:

```py
chart = dict()
lst = [2,4,6,8]
chart[lst[0]] + chart[lst[1]] + chart[lst[2]] + chart[lst[3]]
```

The above code works but I would like to have this automated because my list changes all the time and I don't want to be typing that sum manually every time. I have tried this

```py
sum(chart[i] for i in lst)
```

but then I get an error saying that `list index out of range`.
I guess the python sum is not made for this kind of things but I don't know which other function is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chart1 + chart2` operator is a shorthand for `alt.layer(chart1, chart2)`. If you want to layer multiple charts, you can use `alt.layer` directly:

```
alt.layer(*(chart[i] for i in lst))
```